# AngularJS passing {} instead of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser, asp.net-web-api

Using angularjs 1.4.3, IIS, webapi, Chrome and IE 10

I have a problem where I have a model like so:

```
{ someKey: null }
```

This model was received via a webapi call.

In Angular I submit changes back to the webapi endpoint on the server, the model looks like this when I via it from the network tab on Chrome:

```
{ someKey: {} }
```

This is causing the webapi server to have problems with model state

It seems like Angular changed the null to be an empty object and that seems wrong to me.  An empty object isn't a null.

Any concrete knowledge out there on this?  Is this an issue or bug?

Thanks in advance.

Also I am using Typescript.

Additional details/clarification:

I am posting to the webapi endpoint using $http with something like this:

```
var myHttpConfig: ng.IRequestConfig = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: "http://my webapi url here"),
            timeout:  120000,
            data: {},
            headers:  null
        };
myHttpConfig.headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
myHttpConfig.data = { someKey: { aField: null } };
localPostPromise = this._$http(myHttpConfig);
```

And network view shows this posted:

```
{"someKey":{"aField":{} } }
```

My console logs show this as the data I set in the config:

```
{ \"someKey\":{\"aField\":null } }
```

The original data returned to me in the first place that binds to the model:

```
{ "someKey":{"aField":null } }
```

Comment: How are you submitting the value? `$http` or `$resource` for example? We could do with the code you are using the submit.

Comment: Can you post your method calling WebAPI and then your WebAPI method? I haven't experienced this problem, so more code might give me a chance to recreate it locally.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question :
Use undefined :

```
myHttpConfig.data = { someKey: { aField: undefined } };
```

or iterate over the object properties and do this

```
for (var property in object) {
   if (object.hasOwnProperty(property) && object[property] == null) {
      delete object[property];
}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this behavior is happening from the browser, I don't really want to massage the model data.  So far I get the feeling no one knows much about this one